# Runtime.getRuntime().exec(), executing Java class

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I am executing Java class from inside my application.

```
proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java Test");
```

How can I recognize whether `Test` executed successfully or not (i.e. no exceptions)?

---

Redirecting output / error:

```
proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {
    "java",
    mclass,
    ">NUL 2>test.txt"
});
```

From `cmd`:

```
java Main >NUL 2>test.txt
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
process.waitFor();
int exitCode = process.exitValue();
if(exitCode == 0) { // success }
else { // failed }
```

This works, if the `Test` is designed properly and returns appropriate exit codes (generally, >0 if something went wrong).

If you want to get `Test`s output/error message to determine what was wrong, you should get `proc.getInputStream()` (this returns the output stream of the child process), `proc.getErrorStream()` and read from the input streams in separated threads.

Note that the child process will get blocked if it writes to error/output stream and there are no readers. So reading error/output streams of the process is useful in any cases.

Another option to avoid child blocking is to redirect its error/output to a file and/or to `/dev/null` ('NUL' for windows):

```
Runtime.exec("java Test >/dev/null 2>&1");
Runtime.exec("java Test >/dev/null 2>erroroutput");
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tried redirecting. But when I run it from windows `cmd`, it works fine. Whereas when I use `exec` or process builder, my application just stops and nothing happens, so I have to terminate it. Any advice?

Comment: It is difficult to say definitely. Try to redirect to a file. Does it contain anything after execution?

Comment: Please, take a look at my update. Am I doing it right? File contains nothing either using `cmd` or `exec`.

Comment: Well, although `NIL` still does not work for me, I've decided to put error & output streams to separate threads. Thanks for your help.

Comment: just to not confuse future readers. There is no `exitCode()` method in `Process` class. Only `exitValue()`.

Answer (score 2):

Redirection is done by the shell processor, not by `Runtime.exec()` (at least not on Windows).
You need to execute your command by `cmd.exe`:

```
String command = "cmd /c java -classpath D:\\dev\\temp\\ Main >NUL 2>test.txt";
proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. What if I have to have OS-independent solution?

Comment: you can check the "os.name" system property (System.getProperty) and call the appropriate shell command (sh or cmd). Or a little hack: in Unix/Linux create a link called "cmd" that points to the shell command...

Answer (score 1):

[See the Process class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html)

You can call `proc.waitFor()` to return an integer value. But you have to make sure that all output of the program is handled correctly (e.g. use the `proc.getInputStream()` method).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `proc.exitValue()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Errr... what? Do it this way:

```
int response = (int)(getClass().getClassLoader().findClass("Test").
        getMethod("someStaticMethod", new String[]{}).
        invoke(null, new Object[]{}));
```

This invokes the static method "int someStaticMethod()" of the class "Test" which gets loaded dynamically.

Comment: You might not always want to call the class inside your own JVM, though this is more efficient. Then again, why not just call `Test.sameStaticMethod()`?

Comment: @Marc: Maybe the class name is unknown at compilation time?

Comment: @thejh You may want to execute java code in a separated JVM to avoid 32bit memory limitation, for example.

Comment: I have to call the class in given location by given classname.

Comment: @Little Jeans: Why don't you put it in the classpath?

Comment: @thejh I do put `location` to classpath: `java -cp %location% Test`.

Comment: @Little Jeans: Then why don't you do call it directly? In the same JVM?

Answer (score 0):

You may use ProcessBuilder class of java to execute these files.